# Inserção de dados com PHP utilizando classes e PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sql-insert

Boa noite pessoal. Tenho a tarefa de criar um CRUD completo no site onde trabalho. Entretanto preciso utilizar classes e métodos com PHP. Vejam o que ocorre.

Tenho a classe `usuario.class`, onde coloco todos os atributos e os métodos `Get` e `Set`, assim como os métodos de inserção de dados.

```
public function insert(){

    try{
        $insert = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO web_cadcli(nm_cliente, email_cliente, senha_cliente, id_identpess, img) values(:nome, :email, :Senha, :value,  :imagem);");
        $insert->bindParam(":nome",  $this->nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindParam(":email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindParam("senha", $this->senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindPAram(":value", $this->tpessoa, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindParam(":imagem",$this->imagem, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($insert->execute()){
            return 'ok';
        }else{
            return 'erro';
        }  
    }catch(PDOexception $erro_1){
        echo 'erro'.$erro_1->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Ocorre que ao acessar o template dá erro na linha de inserção onde esta o `execute`. Eu passos os valores através do código  abaixo contidos no formulário.

```
$usuario = new Usuario();

// Cadastro de Usuario
if ( isset($_POST['cadastrar']) ):

    $nome  = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $imagem= $_POST['imagem'];

    $usuario->setNome($nome);
    $usuario->setEmail($email);
    $usuario->setSenha($senha);
    $usuario->setImagem($imagem);

    if($usuario->insert()){

        echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong>OK!</strong> Incluido com sucesso!!! </div>';

    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong>OK!</strong> Erro ao Cadastrar!!! </div>';
    }
endif;
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo à comunidade, Rodrigo. Primeiramente te convido a fazer o [tour] para aprender o básico sobre o site. O [pt.so] possui suporte nativo aos códigos, então evite postá-los em forma de imagem. Basta você [edit] a pergunta, colar o seu código, selecioná-lo e pressionar o atalho `Ctrl+K` para formatá-lo corretamente. Caso queira fazer manual, basta adicionar 4 espaços em branco antes de cada linha de código.

Comment: Já adiantando, no final da linha 64 parece haver um `;` que não faz muito sentido.

Comment: Rodrigo, por gentileza, edite sua questão trocando as imagens por o seu código em texto formatado conforme indicado no comentário acima. Também no final da sua quetão parece que faltou uma imagem.

Comment: Imagino até que, sobre o final dessa sua questão, o melhor mesmo seria criar uma outra questão para tratrar exclusivamente deste tema. Porém, tome cuidado para não gerar uma pergunta que tenda a [respostas baseadas em opinião](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-pergunta-baseada-em-opini%C3%B5es).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela imagem que você postou, o seu problema está nas linhas 64 e 67. Na linha 64 você define o parâmetro `:Senha` (com o "S" maiúsculo). Já na linha 67 você utiliza o parâmetro `:senha` (com o "s" minúsculo).

Ou seja, o parâmetro `:senha` com "s" minúsculo não existe. Edite a linha 64 e troque o parâmetro `:Senha` para `:senha` e irá funcionar.

Comment: Sucesso, ao fazer as correções sugeridas  por Bruno Peres, o insert funcionou perfeitamente...obrigado

Comment: @RodrigoZanetti De nada! Que bom que funcionou. Por favor, caso esta resposta tenha resolvido seu problema lembre-se de [aceitá-la](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079) para informar outros usuários que seu problema foi resolvido e ajudar futuros visualizadores da sua questão. Obrigado!